# touch swipe image to next page in ionic framework?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am creating a simple app with the ionic framework,
I want to go next page when i swipe image left and click.swipe image to next page not working. swipe option not working

this my view.html

```html
<div  class="row card_view">
 <a on-swipe-left="onSwipeLeft()" href="#/app/viewcard"><div class="col card_re"> 
  <img src="img/card1.png" alt=""/>
 </a>
</div>
```

this my controller.js

```js
.controller('MyCardCtrl', function($scope, $state, $stateParams) {
   

    $scope.blog = { id: 1,};
  
  $scope.onSwipeLeft = function (id) {
    console.log('Swiping Left ...');
    $state.go('viewcard', { blogId: id });
  }

    // Set Ink
    ionicMaterialInk.displayEffect();
})

.controller('viewcardCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {
 
  console.log("Param blogId: ", $stateParams.blogId);
  
  var id = $stateParams.blogId;
  
  $scope.blog = { id: id,};
  
    // Set Ink
    ionicMaterialInk.displayEffect();
})
```

Comment: What is your problem? you have not mentioned it!

Comment: @FoadSaeidiNik swipe image to next page not working

Answer (score 0):

The first problem that I can see in your code is that you have not pass the $state var to your myCardCtrl. It causes javascript error!